# Transferring SCIM identities between systems?

Tags: scim

Many talk about how SCIM allows you to transfer identities between systems or service providers.

Are there any built in hooks or API-endpoints for allowing SCIM servers to talk directly to 
other SCIM services? Or are there always a client in between orchestrating the exchange?

Imagine I wanted to transfer my Identities at Google to SalesForce, how would that practically be done and implemented?

I know SCIM provides a REST-API, but somehow someone needs to orchestrate the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

(CSP->CSP) is defined in the point 2.3 of this doc https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-scim-use-cases-01

I can think of many scenarios on how Google and Salesforce would interact, but that decision ultimately belongs to them.